# Setting the doc ID on signup in firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a new document with the id of the user's UID upon signup. However, when testing, nothing happens, not even an error code.

I think its an issue with "db.collection('users').doc("cred.user.uid").set(data);" and how the then function is called afterwards...

Very new to javascript & firebase here, (only 4 days in) so this shouldn't be too hard for you seasoned pros to figure out.

Thanks in advance!

Javascript

```
signupButton.addEventListener('click', signup);

function signup() {
    signupButton.style.display = 'none';
    signupError.style.display = 'none';

    // get user info
    var email = signupEmail.value;
    var password = signupPassword.value;

    // sign up the user
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
        db.collection('users').doc("cred.user.uid").set(data);
        })
        .then(function() {
            window.location.replace('./dashboard/account.html');
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log('Error code: ' + errorCode);
            console.log('Error message: ' + errorMessage);
            signupButton.style.display = 'flex';
            signupError.innerText = errorMessage;
            signupError.style.display = 'flex';
        });
}

    // Trigger button click on enter
    var input = document.getElementById("signupPasswordConfirm");

    // Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        // Cancel the default action, if needed
        event.preventDefault();
        // Trigger the button element with a click
        document.getElementById("signupButton").click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you'd want to return the promise from the Firestore operation so it could be picked up in the promise chain later to find out if there was an error:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
    return db.collection('users').doc("cred.user.uid").set(data);
})
```

Note the `return` statement that propagates the promise returned by `set()`.

Also, are you sure that you want to create a document called "cred.user.uid" literally?  That's what you're doing here.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I added the `return` statement however it seems as if the form isn't moving on to my `.then function` any ideas?

`firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
            return db.coldlection('users').doc(cred.user.uid).set(data);
        }).then(function() {`

Comment: I got it partially working, however it's giving me the error code of `Function DocumentReference.set() requires between 1 and 2 arguments, but was called with 0 arguments.`

@Doug Stevenson How can I just make a document within a collection with just a document ID and no other values?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately and explain in more detail what you're trying to do, and what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: Posted here, thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62598411/cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined-firestore