# Firestore won't add signup email to new database collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When signing up a user, I get no error what so ever, the signup works, but it doesn't create a new DB collection with the signup email.

Furthermore, redirecting the user to `/account/dashboard.html` doesn't work.

Any ideas? I am very new to all of this, only 4 days in so if you could please explain things a little simpler to me that would be very much appreciated.

```
// sign up the user
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
        return db.collection('users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({
            email: "signupForm['signupEmail'].value"
        });
    }).then(function() {
            window.location.replace('/account/dashboard.html');
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log('Error code: ' + errorCode);
            console.log('Error message: ' + errorMessage);
            signupButton.style.display = 'flex';
            signupError.innerText = errorMessage;
            signupError.style.display = 'flex';
            signupForm.reset();
        });
})

    // Trigger button click on enter
    var input = document.getElementById("signupPasswordConfirm");

    // Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        // Trigger the button element with a click
        document.getElementById("signupButton").click();
    }
});
```

My HTML

```
<div class="form-content"><label for="signupPassword-2" id="signupError" class="error-message">Error message</label>
        <div class="form-wrap extra-space"><input type="text" class="text-field w-input" maxlength="256" name="signupEmail" data-name="signupEmail" placeholder="E-mail" id="signupEmail"></div>
        <div class="form-wrap extra-space"><input type="password" class="text-field w-input" maxlength="256" name="signupPassword" data-name="signupPassword" placeholder="Password" id="signupPassword"></div>
        <div class="form-wrap extra-space"><input type="password" class="text-field w-input" maxlength="256" name="signupPasswordConfirm" data-name="signupPasswordConfirm" placeholder="Confirm your Password" id="signupPasswordConfirm"></div>
        <div class="button-wrap"><a id="signupButton" href="#" class="button w-button">Signup</a>
          <h5 class="h5 black centered">Already have an account?</h5>
        </div>
```

Comment: did you try this? in return: db.collection ---> email: signupForm['signupEmail'].value

Comment: This doesn't really make sense, you want me to use ```db.collection ---> email: signupForm['signupEmail'].value```? The correct way to add a DB collection is ```db.collection('users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({``` from my understanding

Comment: yes of course, i just tell to remove the .value before ['signupEmail']

Comment: When removing the .value before, I am still getting the error ```Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.signup (auth.js:46)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (signup.js:54)```

Comment: Just updated the code, @sonEtLumiere any ideas?

Comment: Open Authentication section in firestore console, you should see the users you signed up before.

Comment: Pardon? Why do I need to open the users tab in authentication in firebase? The whole point of this is to create a database that is linked to the user so later on I can add their name, profile pic & other data. @MostafaLabib

Comment: For security purposes Firebase doesn't create collection for users and add them to your collections. You can't access them without firebase admin sdk. briefly firebase creates it's own collection with a known user object that can't be accessed without firebase admin. The only way to change the user data without firebase admin is that the user login and firebase returns that user to you. check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User)

Comment: I am not trying to change the user's data in firebase auth, I am trying to make a collection for that user so I can store profile pictures, addresses & other data down the road.

How would you suggest I collect & store data such as a profile picture & address and link it to that users specific account?

I was thinking make a new collection with the same UID as in firebase auth and link them later somehow. @MostafaLabib

Comment: First of all you can't create a collection with code, you have to setup new collection from firebase console UI. So assuming that you create a new collection called `users` you can create new document for each user by the same code you provided(again assuming that there is already a collection called `users`) but `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` return the user object directly so it should be `cred.uid`

Comment: @MostafaLabib Changing it to ```cred.uid``` still didn't work. I am getting the error "db is not defined" but I do have a collection named ```users```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I forgot to declare the DB variable. Also changed the output of email:

```
// sign up the user
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
        return db.collection('users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({
            email: signupForm['signupEmail'].value
        });
```